# Simple FFT in C# as single core, multi core and OpenCL versions?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, opencl, fft

I searched the web and Stack Overflow for FFT versions in C# and this was asked several times and some answers were given, but...

1. All of the FFT versions I found were optimized for speed but are hard
   to understand.
2. Almost all of those were iterative versions, thus not optimized for
   multi core systems.
3. Opencl versions were optimized for certain gpu models.

As I am working on a case study for single core, multi core, opencl comparison of algorithms, I am looking for the most simple and free C# / Opencl versions of the FFT, working on float[] (real, complex not needed), forward and also inverse optional would be great. It would also be good if they would work on any array-length. Has anyone stumbled upon such?

Answer (score 1):

[This sample source](http://brahma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/92609#1697260) from [Brahma](http://brahma.codeplex.com/) (my open-source project) has both a C# implementation and an LINQ implementation (OpenCL) of [this](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70576) FFT paper from Microsoft research.

The kernels automagically generated by Brahma are:

**The FFT kernel**

```
    __kernel void brahmaKernel(int fftSize,__global float* a,__global float* ib,__global float* c,__global float* id,int size) 
    {
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        int b = ((floor(convert_float((x / fftSize))) * fftSize) / ((int)2));
        int offset = (x % (fftSize / ((int)2)));
        int x0 = (b + offset);
        int x1 = (x0 + (size / ((int)2)));
        float val0A = a[x0];
        float val0B = ib[x0];
        float val1A = a[x1];
        float val1B = ib[x1];
        float angle = (((float)-6.283185) * (convert_float(x) / convert_float(fftSize)));
        float tA = native_cos(angle);
        float tB = native_sin(angle);
        (c[x] = ((val0A + (tA * val1A)) - (tB * val1B)));(id[x] = ((val0B + (tB * val1A)) + (tA * val1B)));
    }
```

**Conjugate and scale kernel**

```
    __kernel void brahmaKernel(float scale,__global float* a,__global float* ib) 
    {
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        (a[x] = (a[x] * scale));(ib[x] = (-(ib[x]) * scale));;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ananthonline, this Microsoft paper is really great. I have found a very naive (but perfect for my purposes) version of the FFT at http://www.lomont.org/Software/ in C#. But I have some problems finding the OpenCL Kernel for FFT in your Source Code. Practically, I need an OpenCL kernel code I can call from C# with the paramters (this is already working here, I got a simple OpenCL Kernel example for reversing vectors). As far as I can see, the Brahme Kernel for FFT is nothing just to simply paste in my project as it is created dynamically, is that right?

Comment: Correct. I will update my answer with the OpenCL kernel that Brahma generates. QuickWatch FTW!

Comment: Hm, okay. Is there a way to get the Brahma kernel for 1D real FFT as such a OpenCL code snippet? 1D real FFT is all I need actually.

Comment: You could modify the source to do a real FFT easily enough, I guess. I don't think you'll find a perfect drop-in for what you need. Some assembly required.